# Query result to variable(Node red)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I have a problem, I want to move value of Object[0] nazwa, which is a result of query (let's say "ab" in this case) to another variable, however I'm new to red node and JS, so I don't know how to do it. Could anyone be so kind and would help me? Right now I have it in function like so:

```
global.set("zmienna",msg.payload.Object[0].nazwa)
```

but it does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global.set("zmienna", msg.payload2[0].nazwa);
```

Explained:

- I see from your debug console that `payload2` is an array, while
  `payload` is a string, so you are probably referring to that
  variable.
- The *object* you see on the right side of your variable in console is
  the type of the variable, not it's name, so you shouldn't use it
  to access your values.

Comment: Couldn't do it earlier due to reddit's policy, did it rn